# How to rename a folder in a GitHub repository without the folder appearing to be deleted?

Tags: git, github

I forked a repository into my GitHub account and must rename a bunch of the files and folders in that repository. When I rename the folder, though, and check the GitHub comparison to the original repo, it only shows that the folder was deleted (it says 0 additions, 20,000 deletions). However, the renamed folder still appears in my account. Anyone have this problem before and know how to get around it?

Answer (score 2):

git does not track folders, only contents of files. (and it tracks the path to those files within the repository).

You can use `git mv` to move all the files in a particular folder, in the repository, to a different folder in the repository.

Then commit this change and push to github.

git's handling of this is very intelligent. For instance if you later have to merge with a branch from before this commit, and that branch changed some of these files, git will automatically figure out that "the files were just renamed and they really correspond to the same content" and apply the changes to them at the new location.

Comment: I've been using git mv but it git still shows the comparison as deletions. When I click on the individual commits, it shows that the files were simply renamed, though. Is this a problem?

Comment: if you apply a commit this way, git should say things like "file renamed without changes" or "file renamed, 99% of lines the same". then you'll know that you are doing it right. ultimately you have to judge the results for yourself to decide if they are what you want, i can't tell you what's a problem.

Comment: @darian19, Git doesn't actually track renames. Deleting a file and adding a new file with the same content is equivalent to renaming.